# Infinispan is not marshalling the whole RefreshableKeycloakSecurityContext when using Spring Session to externalize the session store

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak, infinispan, spring-session

I am using Spring Session to store the application session in an external store, in this case the Infinispan cache.

To do so, I implemented a custom `SessionRepository` that uses Infinispan's `RemoteCacheManager` underneath.

"Normal" objects from the session are stored and unmarshalled without any problem.

My application is integrated with Keycloak for SSO, using Keycloak's Spring Boot Adapter. This sets a session object of type `RefreshableKeycloakSecurityContext`. This is the call to save the session in the remote cache, as you can see the Refreshable... has some attributes (KeycloakDeployment, SpringSecurityTokenStore) that are set:

[image]

But when the Refreshable... attribute is retrieved from the session store, KeycloakDeployment and some other attributes are gone:

[image]

With them gone some functionality provided by the adapter such as refresh token is lost, as you can see in the next bit from Refreshable... where it needs to have a deployment:

[image]

Any idea how I could make those attributes be stored an retrieved from Infinispan?

**UPDATE**

`RefreshableKeycloakSecurityContext` defines `KeycloakDeployment` and `AdapterTokenStore` as transient, so the are not meant to be serialized. The problem with this is that it breaks the adapter when the session is extenernalized of simply serialized... any workaround?

```
package org.keycloak.adapters;
...
/**
 * @author <a href="mailto:bill@burkecentral.com">Bill Burke</a>
 * @version $Revision: 1 $
 */
public class RefreshableKeycloakSecurityContext extends KeycloakSecurityContext {

    protected static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(RefreshableKeycloakSecurityContext.class);

    protected transient KeycloakDeployment deployment;
    protected transient AdapterTokenStore tokenStore;
    protected String refreshToken;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in the adapter version we are using, fixed as stated in the following Red Hat issue: https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-6752?attachmentViewMode=list